# USB-C to 3.0 Micro-B cable not working

Tags: usb-c

My new Intel Realsense D405 camera came with a USB-type B 3.0 (PC) to Micro-B (CAM) cable. This works well.

Now I want to connect the camera via a USB-C to Micro-B cable from Adt-Link (China) This doesn't work.

The cable has a 56K resistor and a capacitor on the USB-C side but nothing on Micro-B side. I read the USB-C cable specification, section 4.5.3.1 Type-C to legacy.

It states that the USB-C port senses a connection on CC via a resistor, connected to ground in the legacy side.

Can the cable work without this second resistor?

Comment: So you bought a cheap cable and it does not work.

Comment: I bought this cable, because is has a small 90 degree micro-b plug and flat ribbon cable for my little rc submarine project. those are hard to find. If someone can say: Hey there is no way that can work, I dont have to think tinker around on it.

Comment: Or did you mean « good ones are hard to find »?

Comment: If it detects what it needs it will run at the appropriate rates, otherwise not.

Comment: You got a wrong cable. Your cable should have 5.1k PULL-DOWN resistor in C-end, so the host Type-C port will recognize the cable (and a device behind it) as a device.

Answer (score 2):

The solution for extension-cabling the Realsense D405 is this:

Use the cable provided with the D405, then use

Cellularize USB C Female to Female Adapter (Black, 3 Pack) 3.1/10Gbps USB Type C Coupler Extender Extension Connector

https://www.amazon.co.uk/Cellularize-Extender-Extension-Connector-Nintendo/dp/B08B4CKFY2?th=1

then use

Long AOC USB 3.1 Type A Male to Type C Male Active Optical Cable 10Gbps 10m

https://www.kenable.co.uk/en/usb-cables-adapters/usb-type-c-cables/usb-c-aoc-cables/11145-long-aoc-usb-31-type-a-male-to-type-c-male-active-optical-cable-10gbps-10m-011145-5055781247354.html

This, after trying a number of expensive failures, has been thoroughly tested and it works.